# Polar to Cartesian coordinates function not outputting the correct data

Tags: javascript, node.js, coordinates, cesiumjs, cartesian

I have a flight path with lat/long and elevation and I need to convert this to cartesin X,Y,Z for cesium.js.
I am running into the wall trying to convert this because I don't seem to be getting the right results from my function.

```
var R = 6371;
function polarToCartesian(latitude, longitude, elevation){
    x = (R+elevation) * math.cos(latitude) * math.cos(longitude);
    y = (R+elevation) * math.cos(latitude) * math.sin(longitude);
    z = (R+elevation) * math.sin(latitude);

    var ar = [x,y,z];
    return  ar;
}
```

I must not either have the correct formula for polar to cartesian or I don't have the correct radius of earth. I found somewhere that my radius should be 6371 but can't seem to find that same SO question for reference.

I am partialy checking if my code is correct by manually adding up the radius of the earth + altitude of the flight path at a given location and seeing if this equals the length of my x,y,z vector.

For example: x,y,z `(3689.2472215653725,3183.2401988117012,13306.90338789763)`
is outputted when I give my function this

```
-93.028,44.6942,7800
```

lat,long,elevation

Could someone point me to find the right js code to accomplish this conversion?

Comment: Not being familiar with polar coordinates when locating points on a globe, [I checked the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates), and don't think you have the right inputs. Can you link to a resource that has polar coordinates on a globe? Also, what is `R` that you assume up top?

Comment: Also, if elevation is defined as distance from the center of the earth, shouldn't that be the same value as `z`, given the three-dimensional grid has (0, 0) at the core of the Earth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using Cesium's built-in functions for this.  See [`Cartesian3.fromDegrees`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Cartesian3.html#.fromDegrees) and [`Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Cartesian3.html#.fromDegreesArray).

For example:

```
var result = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(latitude, longitude, elevation);
```

Note the result will be as Cesium expects: in meters, not kilometers.  This also takes into account the shape of the Ellipsoid, for which the default is [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) (the Earth is not a perfect sphere, as your function presumes).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the Yavascript *per se*. However, your equations are incorrect. You're looking to convert from Lat/Long/Alt to Spherical (aka Cartesian), [which was answered here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4147/lat-lon-alt-to-spherical-or-cartesian-coordinates).

So you could rewrite above as:

```
function polarToCartesian(latitude, longitude, elevation){
    const x = math.cos(latitude) * math.cos(longitude) * elevation;
    const y = math.cos(latitude) * math.sin(longitude) * elevation;
    const z = math.sin(latitude) * elevation;

    return  [x, y, z];
}
```

Comment: are you sure "cartesian" and "Spherical" are the same in Cesium?? I see there are functions to convert from one system to the other.